# How do I pass variable keyword arguments to a function in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

**How can I pass dictionary keys (or other attributes/values) as keywords for keyword arguments?**

The function I want to pass arguments to takes keyword arguments:

```
func(arg1= "foo", arg_a= "bar", firstarg= 1)
```

I have *a lot* of arguments to pass to it, so I'd like to loop it (or if it's possible without a loop, even better):

```
arguments_dictionary={'arg1': "foo", 
                      'arg_a': "bar",
                       ...}

for keyword, value in arguments_dictionary.items():
  func(keyword= value)
```

Sadly, `keyword=` is not recognized as 'arg1'. How can I make this work?

Comment: `func(**arguments_dictionary)`... Remove the loop

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you want to call `func` a single time:

```
def func(arg1="foo", arg_a= "bar", first_arg=1):
   print(arg1, arg_a, first_arg)

arguments_dictionary = {
  'arg1': "foo", 
  'arg_a': "bar",
  'first_arg':42
   }

func(**arguments_dictionary)
```

Comment: Strange how SO works... Sometimes you take hours writing a clear, detailed answer with in-depth explanations of some arcane feature and don't even get an upvote, then you write a minimal answer on a beginner-level question and get five upvotes in a couple minutes <g>

Comment: SO is fundamentally broken for just that. It's simply too large of a community for its own good.