# Passing kwargs via dict to a function and overwriting a single passed kwarg in an elegant way

Tags: python

Thanks to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50989404/how-do-i-pass-variable-keyword-arguments-to-a-function-in-python) I now know how to pass a dictionary as kwargs to a function (and save some space if I repeatedly call a function).

I was wondering whether it is still possible in some way to specifically "overwrite" one of the arguments passed in the dictionary? If I have 100 function calls in which I pass the kwarg-dict and in one of them I need to change one of the kwarg params, is there a nice way to do this?

One solution would be to just write all the params for that call "by hand" and not using the kwarg-dict, but I'm specifically looking to overwrite the param in an elegant way.

Minimal example:

```
def func(arg1="foo", arg_a= "bar", firstarg=1):
   print(arg1, arg_a, firstarg)

kwarg_dictionary = {
  'arg1': "foo", 
  'arg_a': "bar",
  'first_arg':42
   }

# normal call, works - without overwriting any args
func(**kwarg_dictionary)

# The following fails with TypeError: func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'first_arg'
func(**kwarg_dictionary, first_arg=100)  

# The following works, but is very clunky and long:
func(**({k:v for k, v in kwarg_dictionary.items() if k != 'first_arg'}), first_arg=54)
```

Trying to solve it with `functools.partial` also proved less than fruitful, since it expects the arguments to be in order and you cannot provide keyword arguments.

I was wondering whether there is a more elegant solution than the last code line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples of kwargs overriding

```
def func(arg1="foo", arg_a="bar", first_arg=0):
    print(arg1, arg_a, first_arg)


kwarg_dictionary = {
    'arg1': "foo",
    'arg_a': "bar",
    'first_arg': 0
}
# Normal call, works without overwriting any args
func(**kwarg_dictionary)
# foo bar 0


# Create a modified dictionary by updating the value
kwargs1 = dict(kwarg_dictionary, first_arg=1)
func(**kwargs1)
# foo bar 1


# Create a modified dictionary by merging (unpacking)
kwargs2 = {**kwarg_dictionary, **{"first_arg": 2}}
func(**kwargs2)
# foo bar 2


# Create a modified dictionary by copy
kwargs3 = kwarg_dictionary.copy()
kwargs3['first_arg'] = 3
func(**kwargs3)
# foo bar 3


# Make sure the original kwargs haven't been modified
print(kwarg_dictionary)
# {'arg1': 'foo', 'arg_a': 'bar', 'first_arg': 0}
```

Comment: I like most the option of the merge/unpacking in a oneliner :D `func(**{**kwarg_dictionary, **{"first_arg": 1}})`  - compact, nice, readable. Just what I was looking for.